# Looping through Controls in groupbox and setting the Tabstop propperty

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a loop that loops through all the controls in my groupbox and find every control that does have text in it and set the tabstop property to false. But some of the controls' tabstop property has to always be true, even if there is text in the control.

This is my code:

```
    foreach (Control c in deliveryGroup.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Label || c is Button)
        {
            c.TabStop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            {
                c.TabStop = false;
            }
            else if (c.Name == "cmbPKPAdrID")
            {

            }
            else if (c.Name.ToString() == "cmbPKPType")
            {
                c.TabStop = true;  <<------- never enters here
            }
            else if (c.Name.ToString() == "dtpPKPDate")
            {
                c.TabStop = true;  <<------- never enters here
            }
            else
            {
                c.TabStop = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that my program runs, but never runs into the code I have marked with arrows. It jumps out and sets the tabstop property to false even though I want it to set it to true if the control has a specific name.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the line of code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
```

is being executed for the control that you don't want to set `TabStop` to false, and that control currently contains some text.

To fix that, re-order the tests like so:

```
foreach (Control c in deliveryGroup.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label || c is Button)
    {
        c.TabStop = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c.Name == "cmbPKPAdrID")
        {

        }
        else if (c.Name == "cmbPKPType")
        {
            c.TabStop = true;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "dtpPKPDate")
        {
            c.TabStop = true;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
        {
            c.TabStop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            c.TabStop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can simplify to this:

```
foreach (Control c in deliveryGroup.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label || c is Button)
    {
        c.TabStop = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c.Name == "cmbPKPAdrID")
        {

        }
        else if (c.Name == "cmbPKPType")
        {
            c.TabStop = true;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "dtpPKPDate")
        {
            c.TabStop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            c.TabStop = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that its not going into the else if statements i have marked with arrows. so reordering would not help, because it never goes into the else if statement. And i have triple checked the controls name to be sure that its not the issue

Comment: @Lahib But if the control's `Text` property is not blank, your code will set that control's `TabStop` to `false` regardless of the `Name` of the control. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I can see what u mean, but i need it to NOT set the tab property to false on these controls, even if they contain text

Comment: i am using the optimized code u have suggested. and it works. But it still doesn't go into the else if statements.

Comment: @Lahib You will need to run it under the debugger to see what's happening. All I can say is that the code I posted will, for a control with a `Name` property of `"cmbPKPType"` or `"cmbPKPType"` *definitely* go into the `else` part. If it is not doing so, it's because `Name` isn't what you think it is. Perhaps the case is wrong? (Note I also just removed the spurious `.ToString()` from some of the `Name.ToString()` lines.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson If I were you, I would optimise it with switch statement rather than the else if.

Comment: @Jegan Yes, that would work but I didn't want to change the OP's code too much while he's trying to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Found the issue. Very stupid issue. Istead of deliverygroup it should have been pickupgroup :)